# Python3 dbus import error: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, debian

I am trying to use python-mbus for python 3, i have installed it with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dbus
```

However the import fails with:

```
asdf@asdf:~$ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:16:13) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

I have also installed it with:

```
pip3 uninstall dbus-python
```

But i still get the same error:

```
asdf@asdf:~$ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:16:13) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/asdf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/home/asdf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /home/asdf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

This is in sys.path:

```
>>> print (sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/asdf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

Im runnin on Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like `_Py_ZeroStruct` is gone (replaced) in _Python3_ (I've tried on 3.5), but it's still available on _Python 2.7_. So, either go with that, either compile _python3-dbus_ against _Python3_ on your machine (I think source code will have to be modified a bit as well). Or wait... what is the version you installed? (pass _--verbose_ to _pip_)

Comment: Version installed from pip3: dbus-python-1.2.4, and from the package manager: 1.2.4-1+b4.

Comment: Hmm, I downloaded sources for _v1.2.4_ and they don't reference that structure. That's odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how I fixed this (can't comment), but I had the exact same problem and I did:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall dbus-python
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude -f
```

After which aptitude alerted me of some dependency issues with Python, and I "downgraded" a version of Python I had installed on Ubuntu Xenial to the default package provided by Artful. Now, `import dbus` on Python 3.6.3 doesn't pass any errors. Don't know if it actually works well, though.

Maybe you'll be able to fix it in a *similar* fashion, since Debian and Ubuntu packages are usually the same.

Comment: Somehow... only running aptitude update/remove fixed the issue. Not sure if there was a dependency issue (did not see anything besides the ordinary) or a related package was updated (i see python-gi was upgraded). But this fixed the issue! Thanks myxhuang!